# Approval Process step requiring multiple approvers

Tags: approval-process

I have a multi-step Approval Process with a step which will require approvals from multiple individuals in order to advance to Final Approval. I have a Status field on the record. I would like for that field to be updated to say "Approved By User A" or "Approved By User B" upon approval from the appropriate user. And then after the second person approves it the Status will say "Approved By Both".

However, I don't know how to update the field to indicate this because I don't know how to work this type of logic into a single step. Since I have two fields which have the names of the approvers (ApproverA__c ; ApproverB__c). Then I thought I'd be able to check the $User.id and compare to the two fields, and then set the Status as such ("Approved By User B" etc).

However, I don't think Field Updates are triggered until the final approval in a stage. Every time I run the approval process it doesn't get triggered until the last approval.

Any ideas ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach actions can be performed at each steps.**

In the approval step, click on `Show Actions` link to expand that.

[image: Step wise approvals]

So, you will define workflow field updates ("Approved By User A" or "Approved By User B") in each steps and in the final approval action update that as "Approved By Both".

> Approach:

Define approval process as specific above

[image: define]

> Results:

After first step approval, see that "Approval User A" value in the field which is getting updated from Step1 field update.

[image: step 1]

After 2nd step approval, see that "Approved by Both" value in the field which is getting updated from Step 2 field update.

[image: step 2]

**Update based on comments**

Approval action only triggers when both of Unanimous approvers will approve the record in a single step. Workaround could be you need to write batch process to update the record. So when you submit for approval you will initiate batch process in a specific interval and update the record upon unlocking and re-lock again and finally after completion of approval you will terminate the job.

Comment: But I don't think it will run a field update after each approval of a multi-approver stage, will it ? I think it waits until the final approver of the stage has approved - and then it runs the actions associate with approval in the stage.

Comment: did you try that? Salesforce has given the functionality to define approval/rejection actions in each step

Comment: see my answer with justifications and how it will work for you

Comment: I am trying to do all of this within the SAME step. My step requires approvals by both users before advancing to the next step. And I want the Status field to update after the first one approves. It will not advance to the next step at that point. It will still be waiting for the 2nd approval. I don't think I can get it to do a field update at the moment of the first approval of the step because I do not believe Approval Actions of a step are conducted until it receives the last required approval of that step.

Comment: based on the requirement, if you need to change the design, you can do that. What can be achievable I have shown working on my DE

Comment: No - your model is a two step approval process with one approver in each of the steps.My model is a two step proces with TWO approvers in the first step and 1 approver in the 2nd step.And Step 1 of my process requires a unanimous vote by BOTH approvers of that step in order to advance to Step 2.And what I want is for the Status__c field of the record to change after ONE of the required two approvers has approved it.It would say "Still in Step 1 - approved by first approver of Step 1" At that moment it will still be in Step 1 because it requires a unanimous approval. I hope you understood that.

Comment: Yes, understood, approval action only triggers when both of them will approve the record in a single step. Workaround could be you need to write batch process to update the record. So when you submit for approval you will initiate batch process in a specific interval and update the record upon unlocking and re-lock again andfinally after completion of approval you will terminate the job.